# Setting TSD Bit in CR4 causes crash

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I want to restrict the usage of the `rdtsc` instruction such that it can only be executed when in ring 0. According to the Intel Manuals this is possible by setting CR4.TSD which is done by the following kernel module:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

#define TSD_BIT 2

static inline uint64_t getcr4(void) {
    register uint64_t ret = 0;

    asm volatile (
        "movq %%cr4, %0\n"
        :"=r"(ret)
    );

    return ret;
}

static inline void setcr4(register uint64_t val) {
    asm volatile (
        "movq %0, %%cr4\n"
        :
        :"r"(val)
    );
}

static void settsd(void* info) {
    uint64_t cr4 = getcr4();

    cr4 |= (1 << TSD_BIT);
    setcr4(cr4);
}

static void cleartsd(void* info) {
    uint64_t cr4 = getcr4();

    cr4 &= ~(1 << TSD_BIT);
    setcr4(cr4);
}

static int __init init_routine(void) {
    on_each_cpu(settsd, NULL, 0);
    printk(KERN_INFO "CR4.TSD set: %u!\n", (int)(getcr4() >> TSD_BIT) & 1);

    return 0;
}

static void __exit exit_routine(void) {
    on_each_cpu(cleartsd, NULL, 0);
    printk(KERN_INFO "CR4.TSD cleared: %u!\n", (int)(getcr4() >> TSD_BIT) & 1);
}

module_init(init_routine);
module_exit(exit_routine);
```

However, loading this modules instantly crashes the OS. Is there any way to avoid that?

OS information:

```
$ uname -r | cat /etc/debian_version -
7.8
3.2.0-4-amd64
```

Comment: Perhaps there are other parts of the OS (kernel / libraries / daemons) that rely on being able to use `rdtsc`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your way is race with other threads running on the machine. I recommend to look at the code in `arch/x86/kernel/process.c` how do this more or less in proper way.

Check macro `SET_TSC_CTL()`, system call `prctl` as well.